# Поломался порядок блоков на страницах привилегий в справочном центре

Tags: дефект, поддержка, статус-завершено, справка

[Опечатка (отсутствее пробела) в справочной системе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions):

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Даже если что-то кажется очевидным, лучше конкретизировать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это не отсутствие пробела. Они сломали порядок (и, судя по всему, [не первый раз](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345346/260198) ^_^). Сначала должен быть текст "Тип привилегий", а уже потом её имя.

Сделал [пост на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346415/260198).